# what is the correct way to make reusable xml layout for my fragments?

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, android-constraintlayout

so I have 5 different fragments that will have 5 different business logic. but that 5 fragments are actually have the same view/widget in it. each fragment only has a recycler view and a progress bar. and I want to make it simpler and I want to avoid making 5 xml file and each xml file contains a recycler view and a progress bar.

I have 2 approach.

first approach. I make an xml file, lets call it `widgets.xml` , that will contain recycler view and progress bar. and then I will inculde `widgets.xml` to all 5 fragment layout xml. so I will still have 5 layout xml for each fragment, but the xml is simple like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragments.BFragment" >

    <include
        layout="@layout/widgets"
    />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

second approach. I only make one xml that will be used for all my 5 fragments. so I just change the layout in the `inflate` in onCreate view

```
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        setUpRemoteConfigDataForThisFragment()

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_reusable, container, false)
    }
```

which one is the better approach ? or is it any better approach ?

I tend to choose the second approach, but I am worried with the `tools:context` constraint layout attribute (root). if I just make one, then I just have one context for all my fragments. is it ok ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragments.BFragment" > <---- I mean this context

   // child views here

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: The second approach would be preferable. That `tools:context` attribute only applies during design time, so the layout preview can show with the appropriate theme and such. It has no effect at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

create only one xml with recyclerView and progress bar then inflate in as many fragments as you want. it will not gonna create any mess.